# Как с помощью регулярного выражения получить все url с html страницы?

Tags: python, re

Как из кода страницы получить все url?

Есть такая регулярка:

```
pattern = r'''http[\:/a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\=&]*'''
```

но она обрезает некоторые ссылки, то есть если есть ссылка вида "https://ria.ru/20220111/kazakhstan-1767350602.html", то на выходе получается просто "https://ria.ru/20220111/kazakhstan"

Comment: можно добавить тире, чтобы его тоже учитывал http[\:/a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\=&-]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для ваших целей я бы рекомендовал использовать не регулярные выражения, а что-нибудь побыстрее. Например библиотеку `bs4`.

```
import bs4
import requests

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.google.com").text, "html.parser")
urls = soup.find_all("a")
clear_urls = [url.get("href") for url in urls]
print(clear_urls)
```

Ну или [вот полное регулярное выражение для анализа URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python):